# TypeScript: How do I accurately type a function for a complex object (with index signatures)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

#### Overview

I have a function that needs to return a specific spot within an object. Nothing out of the ordinary here. The problem I'm facing is that the object is a mix of known indexes and index signatures and the function seems to be getting confused. I'm hoping that I'm just doing something dumb and typing the function wrong and that one of you fine people can let me know what I'm doing wrong...but this is feeling like a TS linter bug. Any help would be greatly appreciated (including simplification if possible...but I really just care about fixing my particular typing issue).

#### The Function

```
function getCounts<Entity extends EntityType>(entity: Entity, id: string): Counts[Entity][string] {
  return counts[entity][id] ?? []; // throws the error
}
```

#### The Error

```
Type 'CountsWithEntity<Entity1> | CountsWithEntity<Entity2>' is not assignable to type 'Counts[Entity][string]'.
  Type 'CountsWithEntity<Entity1>' is not assignable to type 'Counts[Entity][string]'.
```

#### But it works!

[image: ![enter image description here]

#### And the inferred type, when *using* the function, is correct

[image]

#### Recreation Link

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqAjFAvFA3lAFhAGwIHsAuKAZ2ACdE4BzKAXwG4BYAKFElgWRABMGbFADuxagQAm5KrQbN2HCHACuAW15JQAFXDQsnKFBXaQaTAHJ8RYpYA0Rk31BCr4yVIecmnbtHhtRAgKYUD+NAAfLX4BJX8Y0ABZAEMwYUMOYwBtcN19ADpTCIBdcjzzJRyKvUgil0EyxMElVk4-fSgAYWJVBAoAdWRcCoAeCpMAD2AVKVC84IoAPmEAQWpqFJBRzOMAY16EcjV1ACMIairnM3KG1qX4zp6+4FDMXahs4tAAaQgQKB0Zq1CBND45RAySg0Oj0JrPfpDYAjBrjBqpMBfBp-EAlB5ONocQmcA5wKhQA4vCjkBGvDJOXINEH1MwoMFOYyQlDkbIc4zYPn8imHYDkASOLJC-nfEDkHA2EjkayISzMCVStWCgWSjWUo5QFDqjXXfhyvCERVQSwgXqqphGoX2vklB2AqQCHla8FSvWiqAAZldQplZoVZCtpxAEDtQc1Ov53qFvvIABZY8YQyIw0q9iAUjGtU74y6CUbGWZmTKBOz45D-Z748ZE-zk1AAGzpk2gM0eaRKiApajIguNuMa5v7EXkACsnczOF7UMsYAIKT20bHUqLQpLtakKYb461k5e5AAHHOGj2JH2rVJEEORxrt1KJ8LT1AAOyXm4iRdK3BVFwAB+J8t1dXdjCLYkOAAMz6PYkGIOAoHoCBgFpCg0TMKYZjgOZgX0JYAApMwqew3VkGEGAAShpEUKHLfgSmyORYRKbVjGodDVGoFDfUYmUWMhDjgOAz4ShYKAAHppKgZFqGIURQmRaALkU6gfHaDhSQoYgCAgAoSHoYiBKY-I6hlNkCi5GipNkqZIEQiApCgAADbIcFbcUu1lLMLXDZU7TVERW0NXzQwCpUbVUYKmBKNyoAAWkoVQ9nXCgKAouBiCgHQAGUTA2CQKBJZC9IMoziBMtCMIY4iakKKyKMsLlLBouyZLkiBJicmZXI8rypygHz53NWwAJVZgQqGj9wrG7MrRiuKEuS1L0pCLKoByvLCvUkqyrJfTDOM4jaswhqmSahofNaqR-Xa7IAAYShZfgCkXTqHJ6vqXPcgAiAch1wf7EpSig0oyradoKoqNNKjggA)

#### Full Code (same code within the recreation link)

```
type Entity1 = { hello: string };
type Entity2 = { world: string };
enum EntityType {
  entity1 = 'hello',
  entity2 = 'world',
}
type Entities = Entity1 | Entity2;
type EntityMap = {
  [EntityType.entity1]: Entity1;
  [EntityType.entity2]: Entity2;
};

type CountsWithEntity<Entity extends Entities> = Array<{
  count: number;
  entity: Entity;
}>;
type Counts = {
  [entityKey in EntityType]: {
    [id: string]: CountsWithEntity<EntityMap[entityKey]>;
  };
};

const counts: Counts = {
  [EntityType.entity1]: {
    id1: [
      {
        count: 2,
        entity: { hello: 'hi' },
      },
      {
        count: 1,
        entity: { hello: 'you' },
      },
    ],
    id2: [
      {
        count: 3,
        entity: { hello: 'bye' },
      },
      {
        count: 4,
        entity: { hello: 'cya' },
      },
    ],
  },
  [EntityType.entity2]: {
    id3: [
      {
        count: 6,
        entity: { world: 'earth' },
      },
      {
        count: 5,
        entity: { world: 'place' },
      },
    ],
    id4: [
      {
        count: 8,
        entity: { world: 'dirt' },
      },
      {
        count: 7,
        entity: { world: 'huh?' },
      },
    ],
  },
};

function getCounts<Entity extends EntityType>(entity: Entity, id: string): Counts[Entity][string] {
  return counts[entity][id] ?? []; // throws the error
}

console.log(counts[EntityType.entity1].id1); // expected `[{ count: 2, entity: { hello: 'hi' } }, { count: 1, entity: { hello: 'you' } }]` - success, no TS errors
console.log(getCounts(EntityType.entity1, 'id1')); // expected `[{ count: 2, entity: { hello: 'hi' } }, { count: 1, entity: { hello: 'you' } }]` - success, no TS errors
console.log(getCounts(EntityType.entity2, 'id3')[0].entity.world); // expected `"earth"` - success, no TS errors
```

Comment: Do you mind pasting the function and error as text and not an image please?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that your return type should be `CountsWithEntity<Entity1> | CountsWithEntity<Entity2>`.

That is because the type of `counts[entity][id]` is `CountsWithEntity<EntityMap[entityKey]>`

- Try the following

```
function getCounts<Entity extends EntityType>(entity: Entity, id: string): CountsWithEntity<Entity1> | CountsWithEntity<Entity2> {
  return counts[entity][id] ?? []; // throws the error
}
```

---

**ADDITIONALLY**

You could also use the return type `CountsWithEntity<EntityMap[EntityType]>` to be more dynamic.

```
function getCounts<Entity extends EntityType>(entity: Entity, id: string): CountsWithEntity<EntityMap[EntityType]> {
  return counts[entity][id] ?? []; // throws the error
}
```

Comment: The main problem is that my list of entities is quite long and growing. I was hoping to be able to just update `EntityType`, `Entities`, `EntityMap` and everything else would just continue to work.

I understand that the return type is `CountsWithEntity<Entity1> | CountsWithEntity<Entity2>` but shouldn't it know which one I'm wanting to do based on the `EntityType` sent?

Comment: see `additionally` section just added.

Comment: Your additionally section does get rid of the errors, but it now makes the return type of the function `CountsWithEntity<Entity1> | CountsWithEntity<Entity2>` (which I know is why it started working) which means that I can't call it like this `getCounts(EntityType.entity1, 'id1')[0].entity.hello` since it now doesn't know if `entity` is `Entity1` or `Entity2`. What I'd like to be able to do is pass in the `EntityType` and it infer that the return of the function will be a `CountsWithEntity` for that type. ex. Passing `EntityType.entity1` will know the return is `CountsWithEntity<Entity1>`.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that I _did_ have this working until I was forced to add in the index signature part. I used to have `type Counts = {[entityKey in EntityType]: CountsWithEntity<EntityMap[entityKey]>};` and then the function's return was just `Counts[Entity]` and it worked fine.

Comment: I've updated the description and playground link to have a 3rd console log that, if you change the code to what your "additionally" section's suggests, will begin to error. I've also added an image to show that, with what I had already, the inferred type of the function when you use it is correct.